# How to merge static data type struct and dynamic type map of interface

Tags: go

I'm reading a CSV file and parsing it to some predefined structure (struct in this case), I also need to store all the columns fields which will be different for every CSV file, and the goal is to get unified data structure merging predefined structure and dynamic fields from CSV file.

I have already written a util function that converts struct into map using `json.Marshal` and `json.Unmarshal`, once I convert struct into map I merge it with dynamic fields which is `map[string]interface{}`.

```golang
// StructToMap ..
func StructToMap(v interface{}) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    var preRow map[string]interface{}
    i, err := json.Marshal(&v)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    json.Unmarshal(i, &preRow)
    return preRow, nil
}

// AddMap ..
func AddMap(a map[string]interface{}, b map[string]interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    for k, v := range b {
        a[k] = v
    }
    return a
}

type PreProcessRow struct {
    RawText       string `json:"raw"`
    SanitizedText string `json:"edited"`
}

preProcessRow := &PreProcessRow {
        RawText: "this is an     example text",
        SanitizedText: "this is an example text",
}

dynamicContent := map[string]interface{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}
row, err := StructToMap(&preProcessRow)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
AddMap(row, dynamicContent) // {"raw": "this is an     example text", "edited": "this is an example text", "foo": 1, "bar": 2}
```

This way I am able to merge these two structures but I am looking for better approach (if any) where I don't have to `json.Marshal` and `json.Unmarshal`

Comment: [mergo](https://github.com/imdario/mergo) may help you here.

Comment: Why pass through the `map[string]interface{}` step? Why not create a single struct that embeds the structs you're using per-file, and implement (if needed) a custom `Marshaller` for that type, so in case fields have the same name, and you want to be able to control which field takes precedence over the others

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem the result from the above example can be something like this
`{"raw": "this is an     example text", "edited": "this is an example text", "foo": 1, "bar": 2}` I am trying to get the following result

Comment: Yes, and with type embedding, you'd get exactly that output